# Create column with path thanks to the other row (level + child)

Tags: python, pandas, path, tree

I have this dataframe

```
d = {'level': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2], 'name': ['A', 'B','C','D','F','G','H','X','Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

level   name
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
1        F
2        G
3        H
1        X
2        Z
```

I would like to create a function to add the path of the name based on the level and the previous level in new column (path)

What is the best way to have this kind of result like:

```
level   name   Path
1        A     A
2        B     A/B
3        C     A/B/C
4        D     A/B/C/D
1        F     F
2        G     F/G
3        H     F/G/H
1        X     X
2        Z     X/Z
```

I hope my request is clear

Thank's a lot

Comment: Will the `level` values always be sequences of values like this? What if it skips some values, like `1,2,3,5`? What if it doesn't reset properly, like `1,2,3,2`?

Comment: It's always a sequences!! like 1,2,3....,1,2,3,4...,1,2......

Comment: Try `df['path'] = df.groupby(df['level'].eq(1).cumsum())['name'].apply(lambda x: (x + '/').cumsum().str.strip('/'))`

Comment: @ChrisA, nice one would be good as answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby each "group", using `eq` and `cumsum` to determine these. Then apply `cumsum` again - when applied to string values, it will concat them cumulatively.
We'll use `str.strip` here too to tidy up the trailing `/` characters.

```
d = {'level': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2], 'name': ['A', 'B','C','D','F','G','H','X','Z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['path'] = (df.groupby(df['level'].eq(1).cumsum())['name']
              .apply(lambda x: (x + '/').cumsum().str.strip('/')))
```

[out]

```
   level name     path
0      1    A        A
1      2    B      A/B
2      3    C    A/B/C
3      4    D  A/B/C/D
4      1    F        F
5      2    G      F/G
6      3    H    F/G/H
7      1    X        X
8      2    Z      X/Z
```

Comment: This solution works fine but maybe someone have some improvement to propose. In case of large Dataset (300 000 row) this function take a lot of time. Some idea?